# Which book or books contains all the Stotra of Bhairav

Tags: scripture, identification-request, book-recommendation, manuscripts, bhairava

Books or Scriptures which contains all the stotras of Bhairav

Comment: One book/scripture may not have all the reqd. stuffs .. might be found scattered over various scriptures ... also between Kal Bhairava and Bhairva there is difference. According to Tantras Bhairava is the supreme reality.

Comment: I won't claim all of the mantras and stotras of Kalbhairav but I read this book Rudrayamal Tantram where you will find most of them. The author is Dr. Rudradev Tripathi.

Comment: [Shri Bhairava Upasana](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/shri-bhairava-upasana-NAJ977/) book claims that "The book 'Bhairava Upasana' covers all the aspects and contains all the needed Mantras and Stotras including complete poojan vidhi, arati, chalisa and kawacha."

Comment: @Rickross I need a book in most of the stotras and mantras of Kaal Bhairav or Bhairav are there.

Comment: @Deepeshkumar i just read Rudrayamal Tantram and it contain mantra and stotra section for Bhairav. But there are very few.

Comment: @YDS: I will check.

Comment: @Ram You can read more books on tantra Shastras and collect more stotras and mantras of Bhairava and write one book by self. I mean you won't get all stotras and mantras in one book. Because the writers of tantra Shastras wrote stotras in a way they understood Bhairava. Everyone has their own way of worshipping Bhairava.